# Variable/custom error message in Play! 2 framework scala form

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I would like form validation in Play framework to produce a variable error message depending on collateral results of the validation. How can I do this cleanly?

Specific example -- Say I have a form defined thus:

```
  val f = Form(
    "xml" -> text
      .verifying(
        "xml is incorrect",
        xml => validationError(xml) == None
      )
  )

  def validationError(xml: String): Option[String]
```

What can I do to show the string returned by validationError as the validation error message, instead of the fixed string "xml is incorrect"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create [`Constraint`](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.4/scala/play/api/data/validation/Constraint.html) instance which will handle it. For example:

```
val xmlConstraint = Constraint[String](Some("xml.constraint"), Nil)( xml =>
  validationError(xml).map(msg => Invalid(ValidationError(msg))).getOrElse(Valid)
)

val f = Form("xml" -> text.verifying(xmlConstraint))
```

Also, there is another `apply` method on [`Constraint`](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.4/scala/index.html#play.api.data.validation.Constraint%24) object without specifying the name of constraint.

Comment: Works! Thanks!I got stuck at ValidationResult when researching it on my own (it's a marker trait, completely empty).